# Scheduled task on Django with Windows Server

Tags: django, celery, task

I have a Django project that must be run on Windows Server machine.
I can't install any additional software such as RabbitMQ or Docker. Only pip modules are available.

As far as I know Celery can't work on windows.

Is there a way to implement scheduled tasks in my Django project working in such an environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apscheduler is a very powerful lib that can work in background and maintain tasks. However you need to prepare all tables in your DB to configure such tasks (not so easy like celery)

Answer (score 0):

You can create [django management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run them with the traditional Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: The idea is to create and run tasks via Django interface and DB. In fact I found a solution.  apscheduler

Comment: You didn't note on your question that you wanted to have a web interface to manage your scheduled tasks. My answer was not the one which you expected, but was a possible solution. Please consider at least upvoting. StackOverflow is based on kindness and I took time to answer to you. Thank you

Comment: sure. thanks anyway. However I'm quite new here and don't have enough reputation to vote.